# Windows Phone 8.1 - Call a MessageDialog from ContentDialog

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I´d like to know if I can call a MessageDialog from a ContentDialog.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to do so with a ContentDialog inside another ContentDialog. It did not work. The error message was "Only one ContentDialog can be openend at the same time". I am geussing this will also count for the MessageDialog.

Comment: In my case there is no error. When I call the MessageDialog not hapens.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can call a Message Dialog from a Content Dialog.If **"Only one ContentDialog can be openend at the same time"** error occurs then just call 
**ContentDialog.Hide()** method before calling **MessageDialog.ShowAsync()** Method.